# Can I use DbgEng extension DLL in custom application?

Tags: .net, debugging, windbg, dbgeng

I am curious can I use DbgEng extension without WinDbg. For example is it possible to use DbgEng extension from managed .NET application?

Regards,
Remsy

Answer (score 1):

You can write applications around dbgeng.dll, but it is not a trivial task. Documentation is scarce, and you have to write a lot of plumbing code. However, if you want to build a debugger in managed code, I recommend that you check out [mdbg](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=38449a42-6b7a-4e28-80ce-c55645ab1310&DisplayLang=en.#SystemRequirements), which is a debugger build around `ICorDebug`. Full source code is available, so it is a good source to learn about how to implement a debugger.